# possible conflict of interest by board members

Tags: ethics

Should members of a board for a non profit be voting members from  another organization that plan to use a product board members represent?

Comment: You might also be interested in the [Workplace Stack Exchange site](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.se. This question is as written quite difficult to answer. "Should" can have a lot of meanings. Do you mean legally? morally? culturally? Also somewhat unclear is how exactly the board members can represent a product. / **Can you present the question in a way that makes clearer what sort of framework we are supposed to evaluate the problem in and clear up some details in the problem??**

Comment: Please narrow the question down. It is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Legally a corporate body may be a person. Philosophically, neither it nor its board is a moral or ethical agent.

The individuals who sit on the board are the relevant moral or ethical agents. A corporate body may have rules that define what constitutes a conflict of interest and ethically obligate those agents toward certain actions. Or the corporate body may not.

Operationally, a board depends upon people with an interest in the corporate body which the board oversees.

Where one person may see a conflict of interests, another may see alignment. And the appearance of a potential conflict of interest is not in fact an actual conflict.